# Function output replaces first two rows of my main JSON string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, group-by

I have a JSON query and I am using `console.log` to present it:

```js
var json_data = {"headers":["Month","Value","Number"],"rows":[["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","one",209],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","one",274],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","five",183],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","five",164],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","four",214],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","four",192],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","three",128],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","three",125],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","two",199],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","two",169],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","seven",10541],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","seven",6139],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","six",169],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","six",233]]};

document.getElementById("original").innerHTML = json_data.rows;
```

```html
<div style="background:yellow; "id="original"></div>
<div style="background:red;" id="output"></div>
```

And for the value **"one"** I have two numbers (*209* and *274*).

I am then using a function to groupby which works fine (output). My problem is that when I use the `console.log` for the initial json_data query, the first two rows are different. It seems that my function replaced the first two rows with the rows of the output (red). The function is given here:

```
    function initialGroupBy(rows) {
  const 
    rowMap = new Map(),
    result = [],
    dataTemp = [];

  // Iterate over the rows.
  rows.forEach(row => {

    const
      // Create a key, it is the first elements joined together.
      key = row.slice(0,1).join();

    // Check if the Map has the generated key...
    if (rowMap.has(key)) {
      // The map has the key, we need to add up the values
      const
        // Get the value for the current key.
        storedRow = rowMap.get(key);
        // Add the value of the current row to the row in the map.
        storedRow[2] += row[2];

    } else {
      // The key doens't exist yet, add the row to the map.
      rowMap.set(key, row);
    }

  });

  // Iterate over all the entries in the map and push each value with the
  // summed up value into the array.
  rowMap.forEach(value => {
    result.push(value);
  });


    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
    {
    var object2 = {"date": result[i][0].slice(0,7), "num": result[i][2]};
    dataTemp.push(object2);      
    }

    return dataTemp;

}
```

A full snippet can be found here (Compare the first two rows of the yellow box from the two snippets):

```js
var json_data = {"headers":["Month","Value","Number"],"rows":[["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","one",209],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","one",274],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","five",183],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","five",164],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","four",214],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","four",192],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","three",128],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","three",125],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","two",199],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","two",169],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","seven",10541],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","seven",6139],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","six",169],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","six",233]]};

function initialGroupBy(rows) {
  const 
    rowMap = new Map(),
    result = [],
    dataTemp = [];
    
  // Iterate over the rows.
  rows.forEach(row => {
  
    const
      // Create a key, it is the first elements joined together.
      key = row.slice(0,1).join();
      
    // Check if the Map has the generated key...
    if (rowMap.has(key)) {
      // The map has the key, we need to add up the values
      const
        // Get the value for the current key.
        storedRow = rowMap.get(key);
        // Add the value of the current row to the row in the map.
        storedRow[2] += row[2];
        
    } else {
      // The key doens't exist yet, add the row to the map.
      rowMap.set(key, row);
    }

  });
  
  // Iterate over all the entries in the map and push each value with the
  // summed up value into the array.
  rowMap.forEach(value => {
    result.push(value);
  });
    

 for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
 {
    var object2 = {"date": result[i][0].slice(0,7), "num": result[i][2]};
    dataTemp.push(object2);      
 }

 return dataTemp;

}

const damn = initialGroupBy(json_data.rows);

 
document.getElementById("original").innerHTML = json_data.rows;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =JSON.stringify(damn);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="background:yellow; "id="original"></div>
<br><br>
<div style="background:red;" id="output"></div>
```

I have tried changing the `var` to `const` in many cases. Am I missing a fundamental `JavaScript` case here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your *value* is an Array object, when you save it in your temporary *Map*, you're actually using a reference to your original data structure row.

So in the first *forEach* loop, where you sum the values you're actually changing the original array entry.

The solution is pretty simple, just clone the array:

```
rowMap.set(key, row.slice());
```

Another possibility is to use a different array to save the totals.

Here is your code with the fix.

```js
var json_data = {"headers":["Month","Value","Number"],"rows":[["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","one",209],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","one",274],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","five",183],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","five",164],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","four",214],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","four",192],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","three",128],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","three",125],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","two",199],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","two",169],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","seven",10541],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","seven",6139],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","six",169],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","six",233]]};

function initialGroupBy(rows) {
  const 
    rowMap = new Map(),
    result = [],
    dataTemp = [];
    
  // Iterate over the rows.
  rows.forEach(row => {
  
    const
      // Create a key, it is the first elements joined together.
      key = row.slice(0,1).join();
      
    // Check if the Map has the generated key...
    if (rowMap.has(key)) {
      // The map has the key, we need to add up the values
      const
        // Get the value for the current key.
        storedRow = rowMap.get(key);
        // Add the value of the current row to the row in the map.
        storedRow[2] += row[2];
        
    } else {
      // The key doens't exist yet, add the row to the map.
      rowMap.set(key, row.slice());
    }

  });
  
  // Iterate over all the entries in the map and push each value with the
  // summed up value into the array.
  rowMap.forEach(value => {
    result.push(value);
  });
    

 for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
 {
    var object2 = {"date": result[i][0].slice(0,7), "num": result[i][2]};
    dataTemp.push(object2);      
 }

 return dataTemp;

}

const damn = initialGroupBy(json_data.rows);

 
document.getElementById("original").innerHTML = json_data.rows;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =JSON.stringify(damn);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="background:yellow; "id="original"></div>
<div style="background:red;" id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I have pasted my answer after a help from a JS developer. Yours works fine too!

Comment: Your answer is about using the right approach, and that is fine. Actually both are good, as mine is mostly about the actual issue of the OP.

Comment: Yep. That's why I accepted yours. You answered to the issue. I have just pasted a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

A) The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable -> [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

B) Your problem is that you are actually editing the original object in the initialGroupBy function. Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)  will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A different logic applies here and the result is handy:

```js
var json_data = {"headers":["Month","Value","Number"],"rows":[["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","one",209],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","one",274],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","five",183],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","five",164],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","four",214],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","four",192],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","three",128],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","three",125],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","two",199],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","two",169],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","seven",10541],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","seven",6139],["2018-10-01 00:00:00.0","six",169],["2018-09-01 00:00:00.0","six",233]]};


function groupBy(accumulator, item) {
const [date,extra,value] = item;

const key = date.slice(0,7);

if(!accumulator[key]){
accumulator[key] = 0
}

accumulator[key] += value;
return accumulator;

}

var damn = json_data.rows.reduce(groupBy,{});

damn = Object.keys(damn).map(function(key){
return {date: key, Value: "Total", num: damn[key]};
})

document.getElementById("original").innerHTML = json_data.rows;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =JSON.stringify(damn);
```

```html
<div style="background:yellow; "id="original"></div>
<div style="background:red;" id="output"></div>
```